# Is Typescript not smart enough to infer from an empty object with properties added on later?

Tags: typescript

```
interface ITest {
    objKey: {
        propA: string;
        propB: string;
    };
}

const func: ITest = () => { // Error: Property 'objKey' is missing in type '() => {}'
    const arr = ["objKey"];

    return arr.reduce((obj, name) => { 
        obj[name] = {
            propA: "str1",
            propB: "str2"
        };

        return obj;
    }, {});
};
```

Given the code above, I get the error stated above for `func` even though the properties are added prior to the return.

Is Typescript not smart enough to infer they have been added?  Is there a way for it to not throw an error but ensure that the return still has the interface enforced?

Comment: No, TypeScript  does not do type inference across function boundaries (`reduce` and its callback in your example). Also, in this case it requires knowledge about how `reduce()` works, which TypeScript type system does not have. Also related: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14908

Comment: @artem: I see.  In that case, I'll just have to manually type out the keys and use a function to set the values instead.  Probably makes more sense to do that anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is not typed correct and you can make the parameter optional.
Better would be to use a class instead if you can and return empty class if all else fails.

```
interface ITest {
    objKey?: {
        propA: string;
        propB: string;
    };
}

const func = ():ITest => {
    const arr = ["objKey"];

    return arr.reduce((obj, name) => { 
        obj[name] = {
            propA: "str1",
            propB: "str2"
        };

        return obj;
    }, {});
};
```